# Prevent figure from being cut in "standalone" class

Tags: standalone

I'm writing a script to extract LaTeX-generated images and save them as PDF files. I have an issue with too large images. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
  \begin{picture}(17,5)(-1.5,0)
    \thicklines
    \put(1.2,3.5){$x_7$}
    \put(1.2,1){$x_7$}
    \put(2,3.5){\line(2,-1){1}}
    \put(2,1){\line(2,1){1}}
    \put(3,1.5){\line(0,1){1.5}}
    \put(3,1.5){\circle*{0.15}}
    \put(3,3){\circle*{0.15}}
    \put(3,3){\line(2,1){1}}
    \put(3,1.5){\line(2,-1){1}}
    \put(4.2,3.5){$\theta^i$}
    \put(4.2,1){$\theta^j$}
    \put(3.2,2.2){$\theta$}
    \put(6,2.2){\bf+}
    \put(8.2,3.5){$x_7$}
    \put(8.2,1){$x_7$}
    \put(9,3.5){\line(2,-1){1}}
    \put(9,1){\line(2,1){1}}
    \put(10,1.5){\line(0,1){1.5}}
    \put(10,1.5){\circle*{0.15}}
    \put(10,3){\circle*{0.15}}
    \put(10,3){\line(1,-2){1}}
    \put(10,1.5){\line(1,2){1}}
    \put(11.2,3.5){$\theta^i$}
    \put(11.2,1){$\theta^j$}
    \put(9.6,2.2){$\theta$}
  \end{picture}
\end{document}
```

When I compile it with pdflatex I obtain a cut image:

[image]

Can I prevent it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just don't use `varwidth`, which is not necessary. The `\setlength` command belongs to the preamble.

<sup>The command `\bf` has been deprecated for 25 years</sup>

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(17,5)(-1.5,0)
    \thicklines
    \put(1.2,3.5){$x_7$}
    \put(1.2,1){$x_7$}
    \put(2,3.5){\line(2,-1){1}}
    \put(2,1){\line(2,1){1}}
    \put(3,1.5){\line(0,1){1.5}}
    \put(3,1.5){\circle*{0.15}}
    \put(3,3){\circle*{0.15}}
    \put(3,3){\line(2,1){1}}
    \put(3,1.5){\line(2,-1){1}}
    \put(4.2,3.5){$\theta^i$}
    \put(4.2,1){$\theta^j$}
    \put(3.2,2.2){$\theta$}
    \put(6,2.2){\textbf{+}}
    \put(8.2,3.5){$x_7$}
    \put(8.2,1){$x_7$}
    \put(9,3.5){\line(2,-1){1}}
    \put(9,1){\line(2,1){1}}
    \put(10,1.5){\line(0,1){1.5}}
    \put(10,1.5){\circle*{0.15}}
    \put(10,3){\circle*{0.15}}
    \put(10,3){\line(1,-2){1}}
    \put(10,1.5){\line(1,2){1}}
    \put(11.2,3.5){$\theta^i$}
    \put(11.2,1){$\theta^j$}
    \put(9.6,2.2){$\theta$}
  \end{picture}
\end{document}
```

[image]